# PHP : How to remove a duplicate array item ONCE

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$arr1 = [1,2,2,3,3,3];
```

Is there any method by which I can delete a duplicate value once like,

```
some_function($arr1,3);
```

which gives me the ouput `$arr1 = [1,2,2,3,3]`

Comment: This is such a specific requirement that there isn't a built-in method. Count the number of instances in the array, if there are > 1 then find and remove one.

Comment: @JJJ Yep you are right. But could you provide me with some more details?

Comment: check answers below/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment, check if there are more than one of the element you're searching for, then find and remove one of them.

```
function remove_one_duplicate( $arr, $target ) {
    if( count( array_keys( $arr, $target ) ) > 1 ) {
        unset( $arr[array_search( $target, $arr )] );
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: As for this question, here's a slight refinement (replace `array_search()` with `current()`) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/501c2e3ce34d98446465ca13815a3cf971c60267

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
function removeduplicate($myarray,$needle) {

    if (($nmatches = count($matches = array_keys($myarray,$needle))) >= 2) {

        for ($i=0; $i<$nmatches; $i++) {
            if ($matches[$i+1] == (1+$matches[$i])) {
                array_splice($myarray,$matches[$i],1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $myarray;
}
```

To use the function...

```
$arr1 = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,7,3,3];
$newarray = removeduplicate($arr1,3)
print_r($newarray);
```

***EDITED***:

If you want the function to modify your original array directly, you can do it (the function will return `true` if a character has been removed or `false` if not)...

```
function removeduplicate(&$myarray,$needle) {

    if (($nmatches = count($matches = array_keys($myarray,$needle))) >= 2) {

        for ($i=0; $i<$nmatches; $i++) {
            if ($matches[$i+1] == (1+$matches[$i])) {
                array_splice($myarray,$matches[$i],1);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

So, now you can do...

```
$arr1 = [1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,2,2];
removeduplicate($arr1,2);
print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: I think if your make the first `if-condition` as a while loop, you can actually match more then one duplicate number.

Comment: I've changed the approach. Thanks @Sysix!

Answer (score 0):

This function will copy the array skipping only the second instance of the specified element.

```
function removeOnce($array, $elem) {
    $found = 0;
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $x) {
        if ($x == $elem && (++$found) == 2) {
            continue;
        }
       $result[] = $x;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method will do a lot of iterating to build the new array.  A better / more efficient method would be to remove/unset one duplicate and break from the loop.